# SSE event stream with Parse CloudCode

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, server-sent-events, sparkcore

I am trying to create a SSE event stream with Parse CloudCode so it can consume data sent from a SparkCore. I have it working fine if embedded in a webpage, I'm just unsure of how to do it Parse CloudCode. Here is JavaScript I am working with:

```
document.getElementById("uptime").innerHTML = "Waiting for data...";

var deviceID    = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
var accessToken = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
var eventSource = new EventSource("https://api.spark.io/v1/devices/" + deviceID + "/events/?access_token=" + accessToken);

eventSource.addEventListener('open', function(e) {
     console.log("Opened!"); },false);

eventSource.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
     console.log("Errored!"); },false);

eventSource.addEventListener('Uptime', function(e) {

      var parsedData = JSON.parse(e.data);
      var tempSpan   = document.getElementById("uptime");
      var tsSpan     = document.getElementById("tstamp");

      //Display data on webpage
      tempSpan.innerHTML = "Core:" + parsedData.coreid + " | Data: " + parsedData.data;
      tempSpan.style.fontSize = "28px";

      tsSpan.innerHTML = "At timestamp " + parsedData.published_at;
      tsSpan.style.fontSize = "9px";

}, false);
```

What I would ideally like to do is take in `parsedData.data` and create a new row in my Parse database.

Does Parse support SSE streams??

Comment: you can run your own middle-man machine to turn sse messages into parse events

Comment: Parse does not support streams/sockets at this time.

Comment: @dandavis So your saying to setup a middle-man running the SSE stream, when I get I hit there, create a parse event to call a function on Parse CloudCode passing in the data? My web scripting knowledge is embarrassingly limited.

Comment: yeah, kinda like a "proxy" from your SSE to parse. i know that's not sexy, but it always works.

Comment: @dandavis got it working. If you want to put that in an answer I'll accept it and +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

random, I would say no.  The SSE protocol requires you to send the REST Get request and then listen to inbound TCP stream indefinitely to capture the stream of JSON objects being sent continuously.  I would imagine the REST client implementation at Parse doesn't handle this kind of unknown/indefinite response length.  I